# window is not defined in React with SSR

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Why is this line:

```
const store = configureStore(window.INITIAL_STATE);
```

causing this error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I'm trying to update a pretty old code base (React 15.2 with SSR, react-router v.3x).

The code right under the problem line is

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={getRoutes(store)}/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

UPDATE:
Here is the configureStore.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import rootReducer from '../reducers'

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const logger = createLogger();
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk, promise, logger)
  );

  // this is from webpack 1.x
  // if (module.hot) {
  //   // Enable hot module replacement for reducers
  //   module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
  //     const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers');
  //     store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
  //   });
  // }

  return store;
}
```

If that helps

UPDATE 2

```
Router.match({ routes: routes.default(store), location: req.url }, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err.message);
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.status(302).redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    } else if (renderProps) {
      var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(Provider, { store: store },
        React.createElement(Router.RouterContext, renderProps)
      ));
      res.render('layouts/main', {
        html: html,
        initialState: store.getState()
      });
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(404);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The `window` object doesn't exist on the server.

Comment: @Tholle - yea I get that. The code base has been working fine. This is actually one of the last things that I'm dealing with to update it all.

Comment: Alright, that's frustrating. It's hard to say without seeing all the context, but maybe you could just use an empty object as initial state on the server? `const store = typeof window === "undefined" ? {} : configureStore(window.INITIAL_STATE);`

Comment: @Tholle - I added my configureStore.js in the UPDATE above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are doing ssr correctly, you should have two different entry files, one for the client side (browser) and one for the server side (nodejs)

For the client side, this line of code gets executed `const store = configureStore(window.INITIAL_STATE);`

for the server side,

```
const initState = getStateSomehow();
const store = configureStore(initState);
```

And when the server renders the initial HTML to the client, inject script so window.INITIAL_STATE has the same value

```
<script>
    window.INITIAL_STATE = ${JSON.stringify(initState).replace(/</g, '\\u003c')}
</script>
```

I recommend reading more on https://redux.js.org/recipes/server-rendering